# Jenkins - Remove unwanted console output lines

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I am new with Jenkins and would like to know:

1st) What would be the better practice to run a shell script? Paste the entire script in "**Execute shell on remote script**"? Or call the sh /root/script.sh script?

2nd) When I launch a script in "**Run shell script on remote**" it returns me all lines of script in console output:

**SCRIPT:**

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                  
set +x
ONE=1
echo $ONE
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT:**

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                  
set +x
ONE=1
echo $ONE
1
[SSH] exit-status: 0
Finished: SUCCESS
```

In the shell local console command `set + x` usually works.

Comment: I don't see a question here! can you elaborate a bit more? and Why do you have `set +x` on your Jenkins bash script? Remove the line and you won't see the console output other than the `echo` command output!

Comment: I would like jenkins the output console does not print the lines which define variable and comments.
I want him to present only What do I launch the echo.
He's showing me everything!
You see?

Comment: Remove the line `set +x`

Comment: In remote shell he always shows me all lines both echo as variables even with or without the option set +x

Answer (score 2):

> 1st) What would be the better practice to run a shell script? Paste
>   the entire script in "Execute shell on remote script"? Or call the sh
>   /root/script.sh script?

Definitely a separate file, you'll be able to put that into version control system like GIT and easily manage changes to the file.

> 2nd) When I launch a script in "Run shell script on remote" it returns
>   me all lines of script in console output:

Not sure about this one, but try changing !/bin/bash into #!/bin/bash. Perhaps the file isn't seen as actual script?

Comment: 1) Right! Just I place doing because I could not pass the variable jenkins password for my remote script.sh only location. Thanks for the info, I try to call the remote script.

2) I forgot to add # in the post above, already own in my script #! / Bin / bash